Firebase config file not being considered on transpilation
I have this fastify backend app, it uses typescript. Looks like it's trying to find my firebase configuration (a json file) inside the dist folder (the output folder) but it only exists in the not-compield version of the project (src). This is the error message:
node:fs:448
    return binding.readFileUtf8(path, stringToFlags(options.flag));
                   ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\edwil\OneDrive\pizzaria\pizzaria-da-vila\dist\config\pizzaria-da-vila.json'
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:448:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edwil\OneDrive\pizzaria\pizzaria-da-vila\dist\config\firebase-config.js:33:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edwil\OneDrive\pizzaria\pizzaria-da-vila\dist\models\orders-model.js:6:43)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\edwil\\OneDrive\\pizzaria\\pizzaria-da-vila\\dist\\config\\pizzaria-da-vila.json'
}

Node.js v20.17.0

This is my tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

And my package.json
{
  "name": "pizzaria-backend",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src --exec ts-node src/server.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "fastify": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.7.4",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  }
}

I tried to run after building it. Also tried to build and run in the same command. Updating tsconfig include to: "include": ["src/**/", "src/config/.json"], also didn't work

If you need to read that JSON file at runtime in your code, then you should consider arranging to copy that file into the place where it's expected to exist, perhaps immediately after tsc does its work.  Changing tsconfig won't help you at all here since tsc isn't reading it directly - only the transpiled code in dist\config\firebase-config.js is using it instead (one would guess, based on the error message).  It might also be possible to configure tsc to also copy JSON files as part of its business.

Thank you for your answer, sir! Your comment led me to the solution.
